# How i can start Maven build from outside project folder?

Tags: maven

I have project files in folder:

```
./project/java_files/
```

if i go to `java_files && run mvn package` - all works correctly.
but how i can start same from `./project` folder?
I mean without `cd ./java_files` of course...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can run maven command as below, passing path to pom.xml

```
mvn package -f /path/to/pom.xml
```